# Unable to read pom.xml in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

I am able to build the code from the dependencies as a free style jenkins job. But when I creating a pipeline and during the package stage I am getting the following error:
*************Error**************

`POM file $workspace/project/pom.xml specified with the -f/--file command line argument does not exist`

How can I make pom.xml readable I am using maven here.

Comment: Please show the whole command you are trying to execute etc.

Comment: I am trying to build from root pom which is in the git repository and also checkout is completed from the same repo.

Comment: sh "${mvnCMD} -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS} -f ${workspace}/<job-name>/pom.xml clean package -Dbranch=${branch_name} -DbuildId=$BUILD_ID -DskipTests"

Comment: Why using `sh` instead of `tool` of pipelines. Furthermore why using `-f ...` if your configuration is correct then you are already in your workspace... furthermore `-s ..` is a bad idea.Better use config file provider plugin of Jenkins and use that (incl. credentials support)... apart from using `-Dbranch=..`  use multi branch pipelines does things automatically... and `buildId ? And building but without tests? Huh.... What are you trying to accomplish with your freestyle Job? Building Maven projects is best to use pipeline or Maven job type... ?

Comment: configFileProvider(
                           [configFile(fileId: 'FILE_ID', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')])

Comment: already using config file provider plugin

Comment: My curiosity was like pom was nonreadable in spite of giving the correct path??

Comment: Check for the necessary user permission

Comment: can you please let me know what specific permission do I need?

Comment: I am having sufficient permissions actually